# How to decode a named array of json objects in Swift

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I have a named array of json objects which I receive via an API call.

```
{
    "Images": [{
        "Width": 800,
        "Height": 590,
        "Url": "https://obfuscated.image.url/image1.jpg"
        }, {
        "Width": 800,
        "Height": 533,
        "Url": "https://obfuscated.image.url/image2.jpg"
        }, {
        "Width": 800,
        "Height": 478,
        "Url": "https://obfuscated.image.url/image3.jpg"
    }]
}
```

The objects are of type Image, which I have defined and have a decode function which can decode a single Image object. Image looks like:

```
struct Image : Codable {
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    let url: String

    enum ImageKey: String, CodingKey {
        case width = "Width"
        case height = "Height"
        case url = "Url"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
    {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: ImageKey.self)
        width = try container.decodeIfPresent(CGFloat.self, forKey: .width) ?? 0.0
        height = try container.decodeIfPresent(CGFloat.self, forKey: .height) ?? 0.0
        url = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .url) ?? ""
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws
    {
    }
}
```

I have a written a test for this scenario but this is where I am stumped! The test fails (naturally) and looks like this:

```
func testManyImages() throws {

    if let urlManyImages = urlManyImages {
        self.data = try? Data(contentsOf: urlManyImages)
    }

    let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    if let data = self.data {
        if let _images:[Image] = try? jsonDecoder.decode([Image].self, from: data) {
            self.images = _images
        }
    }

    XCTAssertNotNil(self.images)
}
```

My question is this:

**How do I access the array of Images via the name "Images" or otherwise?**

Thanks for reading and as always any help always appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your Codable structure is wrong. It should be :

```
struct JSONStructure: Codable {
    let images: [Images]
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case images = "Images"
    }
}

struct Images: Codable {
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat
    let url: String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case width  = "Width"
        case height = "Height"
        case url    = "Url"
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        width         = try container.decodeIfPresent(CGFloat.self, forKey: .width) ?? 0.0
        height        = try container.decodeIfPresent(CGFloat.self, forKey: .height) ?? 0.0
        url           = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .url) ?? ""
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    }
}
```

And then :

```
if let data = self.data {
   if let decoded = try? jsonDecoder.decode(JSONStructure.self, from: data) {
       print("Decoded : \(decoded)")
       self.images = decoded.images
   }
}
```

Logs :

> Decoded : JSONStructure(images: [DreamSiteradio.Images(width: 800.0,
>   height: 590.0, url: "https://obfuscated.image.url/image1.jpg"),
>   DreamSiteradio.Images(width: 800.0, height: 533.0, url:
>   "https://obfuscated.image.url/image2.jpg"),
>   DreamSiteradio.Images(width: 800.0, height: 478.0, url:
>   "https://obfuscated.image.url/image3.jpg")])

Comment: Thanks @Sharad Chauhan

Answer (score 2):

You can create 2 structs instead of 1 for parsing the complete response, i.e.

```
struct Response: Codable
{
    let images: [Image]?
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case images = "Images"
    }
}
struct Image : Codable
{
    var width: CGFloat?
    let height: CGFloat?
    let url: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey
    {
        case width = "Width"
        case height = "Height"
        case url = "Url"
    }
}
```

Since there are nested levels in the response, this is why I've created multiple structs.

Also you don't need to write explicit container for parsing. `Codable` will do it on its own.

You can simply decode the sample `JSON` with:

```
if let data = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8)
{
    let response = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data)
    print(response?.images)
}
```